# How do I choose the branch to merge into in git?

Tags: git, version-control, merge, branch, git-merge

At work we use Git a lot but lately we have been experiencing lots of trouble when we try to do merges between branches.

We have two development teams and I am the one who takes care of merging the work each team do. As we work in diferent parts of the application I wonder **if there is a normal flow when merging**.

That is why I aske: How it should we merge the branches: merging branch A into B or merging branch B into A?

## Situation:

We are not working on branch master. We left it as stable. There are branches: "**Team A**" and "**Team B**".

Team A work in some controllers while Team B work in some views. When the time to share code come, I merge the branches.

What I have done is merge Team B into Team A, but we have **had merge conflicts**, however, we have been able to solve them.

In order to work smooth and avoid merge conflicts (that sometimes are hard to solve) I am trying to figure out a better way to work between branches, but nothing had come to my mind.

Comment: Which branch merges into which is completely defined by your workflow. For example, you could create a feature branch from `master` and work on a feature. When the feature is done, you would naturally merge `feature` into `master`, right?

Comment: What is the trouble you are experiencing? What problems do you need a better branching model to solve? Something similar to http://blog.carbonfive.com/2010/11/01/integrating-topic-branches-in-git/ or http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/ is pretty common but it really depends on what your process requires.

Comment: @xbonez right now, we are not merging anything to master branch. We have branches "team a" and "team b". We left master stable and started working on team branches, however, from time to time, teams need to share code and there's where merge, sometimes, give trouble (although we have been able to fix them)

Comment: Please start with concrete details for one specific situation you're having trouble with.

Comment: @jthill edited. Hope you can understand better the situation now. Wait for comments.

Comment: It doesn't matter which branch gets merged into which - if there are conflicts, changing the merge order won't fix them. They will have to be manually fixed

Answer (score 1):

In my experience it is most effective to have contributions flow in a single direction from branch to branch and repository to repository. While git can support merging in any direction that usually leads to confusion.

Define a clear workflow for changes which are `git push`ed "upstream" and `git pull`ed "downstream". For example a developer might:

1. `pull` from a `development` branch to get the latest revision.
2. Create a feature branch and commit some changes.
3. `push` those changes upsteam either by merging back into the `development` branch and pushing that or by pushing their feature branch (or patch) to a pull request, code review process, or other remote integrator.

Similarly work done by developers is pushed upstream to deployment branches, release versions, or other more stable branches of the repository.

This can produce a [clean history of topic branches](http://blog.carbonfive.com/2010/11/01/integrating-topic-branches-in-git/). Normally I like to make sure each branch's author is responsible for handling the merge. In most cases they are best equipped to resolve any conflicts or they have not yet publicized their branch so they can rebase and rewrite their commits into a fast forward change which does not conflict.

Don't be afraid to create more short lived branches. If multiple features in flight need a small change find their common ancestor in the history, branch from there, apply the change, and allow both feature branches to pull it into their work.

In some cases merge conflicts are inevitable. If you have two public branches (branches anyone might pull from so you don't want to rewrite history) which conflict then I would pull from the upstream branch, resolve conflicts on the downstream branch, and always push a conflict free merge back upstream. Thus the responsibility for resolving conflicts again falls on the person contributing new conflicting changes to the more authoritative "upstream" branch.